# preg_match_all and preg_replace in Ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I am transitioning from php to ruby and I am trying to figure the cognate of the php commands preg_match_all and preg_replace in ruby.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The equivalent in Ruby for `preg_match_all` is [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181), like so:

In PHP:

```
$result = preg_match_all('/some(regex)here/i', 
          $str, $matches);
```

and in Ruby:

```
result = str.scan(/some(regex)here/i)
```

`result` now contains an array of matches.

And the equivalent in Ruby for `preg_replace` is [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186), like so:

In PHP:

```
$result = preg_replace("some(regex)here/", "replace_str", $str);
```

and in Ruby:

```
result = str.gsub(/some(regex)here/, 'replace_str')
```

`result` now contains the new string with the replacement text.

Answer (score 3):

For preg_replace you would use `string.gsub(regexp, replacement_string)`

```
"I love stackoverflow, the error".gsub(/error/, 'website') 
# => I love stack overflow, the website
```

The string can also be a variable, but you probably know that already. If you use gsub! the original string will be modified.
More information at http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186

For preg_match_all you would use `string.match(regexp)`
This returns a MatchData object ( http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html ).

```
"I love Pikatch. I love Charizard.".match(/I love (.*)\./)
# => MatchData
```

Or you could use `string.scan(regexp)`, which returns an array (which is what you're looking for, I think).

```
"I love Pikatch. I love Charizard.".scan(/I love (.*)\./)
# => Array
```

Match: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001136

Scan: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181

EDIT: Mike's answer looks much neater than mine... Should probably approve his.

Answer (score 0):

Should be close for preg_match

```
"String"[/reg[exp]/]
```