# How to allow only numeric charaters using preg_replace in ruby and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Am trying to allow and print only numeric characters.
To this effect, I have reference solution found here which uses 
`str.gsub("/some regex/", '')` 
method but cannot get it to work.
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791718/preg-match-all-and-preg-replace-in-ruby)
here is the code

```
 mystring= 'Food1248is read 100'
    result = mystring.gsub("[^0-9]", '')

    print(result)
```

I need to only get the numbers from the string variable above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mystring= 'Food1248is read 100'    
mystring.gsub(/\D/, '')
=> "1248100"
```

Comment: Thanks Umesh. I never guess that.  The regex [^0-9] works very well with my python flask and Django apps.  you saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring= 'Food1248is read 100'
p mystring.scan(/\d+/).join
```

output

```
"1248100"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring= 'Food1248is read 100'
mystring.gsub(/[a-zA-Z]/, '').delete(' ')
```

Output:

```
1248100
```

Answer (score 0):

In `str.gsub("/some regex/", '')` "/some regex/" is not a regex, it is a string. `/some regex/` is a regex; just as `/[^0-9]/` which would work.